# How can I append to list in excel based on some condition?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to figure out the best approach to perform a routine task in excel. I have an excel file with columns as below, and it needs to be updated from time to time

```
ID  country  department  expense_group  Amount  approvers1  approvers2
```

The column approvers1 and 2 contain a list of comma separated userIDs - users who are authorized to approve the given expense up to the "Amount".

As people leave the company, move across departments, new people join in, the excel data is updated manually. I am looking at ways to simplify this task preferably with some VBA / PowerQuery.

I am looking for ways to perform the below tasks in excel. So far I think the only approach would be use VBA but would like to hear any other possible approaches

- Replace a certain userID with another userID against a certain expense_group/department
- Append a certain userID in a comma separated list against a certain expense_group/department
- Append a certain userID in a comma separated list only where another given userID is present

Your suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Why don't you make the program in java with sql (or other db language) and then create an export to excel for the db?

Comment: So, it is not complicated to update an user from a comma separated lis, but you must better describing what this "update" means... What does "against a certain expense_group/department" mean? That the update should take place only for a specific name/string on `expense_group` column? Then, you want replacing it with something else or/and only delete it form the list?

Comment: Should the code look in both approvers1/approvers2 columns? I missed the appending part... So, for such a case you should supply another user name like a marker, to append the list only if it already exists (the last case) or append all lists of a specific `expense_group`? Would such an understanding be a correct one. It would be good to show us not only the header. Some data in the table could help us helping you with a real working code, I think...

Comment: It is good, after placing a question to come here frequently to answer the clarification questions, if any...

Comment: @FaneDuru my apologies for the delayed response. yes your assumption is mostly correct. The code needs to look at both approvers1 and approvers2. So for example, let's say a person p1 who is present in the list of approvers for expense e1 for department d1 is moving to another department d2 and will be approver for expense e2. He will need to be appended to list of approvers of e2 in department d2 and removed from list of approvers of expense e1 from department d1. Similarly if the person is leaving the company and another person p2 is taking their place, this person would replace p1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my assumptions from the above comments are correct, please test the next code:

```
Sub updateUsers(rngProc As Range, strUser, strGroup As String, Optional strReplace As String, Optional userPrezent As String)
   Dim arr, arrApp1() As String, arrApp2() As String, mtch, i As Long
    arr = rngProc.Columns("D:G").Value2
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        If arr(i, 1) = strGroup Then 'strReplace <> ""
             arrApp1 = Split(Replace(arr(i, 3), " ", ""), ",")
             arrApp2 = Split(Replace(arr(i, 4), " ", ""), ",")
             If strReplace <> "" Then
                'check in approvesrs1:
                mtch = Application.match(strUser, arrApp1, 0)
                If IsNumeric(mtch) Then  'if strReplace does not exist
                    If Not userExists(strReplace, CStr(arr(i, 3))) Then
                          arrApp1(mtch - 1) = strReplace  'it replaces strUser
                    Else                                   'only eliminates strUser
                          arrApp1(mtch - 1) = arrApp1(mtch - 1) & "#$@"
                          arrApp1 = Sort(arrApp1, arrApp1(mtch - 1) & "#$@", False)
                    End If
                    arr(i, 3) = Join(arrApp1, ",")
                End If
                'check in approvesrs2:
                mtch = Application.match(strUser, arrApp2, 0)
                If IsNumeric(mtch) Then  'if strReplace does not exist
                    If Not userExists(strReplace, CStr(arr(i, 4))) Then
                          arrApp2(mtch - 1) = strReplace  'it replaces strUser
                    Else                                   'only eliminates strUser
                          arrApp2(mtch - 1) = arrApp2(mtch - 1) & "#$@"
                          arrApp2 = Sort(arrApp2, arrApp2(mtch - 1) & "#$@", False)
                    End If
                    arr(i, 3) = Join(arrApp1, ",")
                End If
             ElseIf userPrezent <> "" Then
                'Appending only if a user name (userPrezent) exists:
                'check in approvesrs1:
                mtch = Application.match(userPrezent, arrApp1, 0)
                If IsNumeric(mtch) Then
                    If Not userExists(strUser, CStr(arr(i, 3))) Then
                        arr(i, 3) = arr(i, 3) & "," & strUser 'append it only if strUser does  not exist
                    End If
                End If
                'check in approvesrs2:
                mtch = Application.match(userPrezent, arrApp2, 0)
                If IsNumeric(mtch) Then
                    If Not userExists(strUser, CStr(arr(i, 4))) Then
                        arr(i, 4) = arr(i, 4) & "," & strUser 'append it only if strUser does  not exist
                    End If
                End If
            Else
                'appending without any condition
                If Not userExists(strUser, CStr(arr(i, 3))) Then
                    arr(i, 3) = arr(i, 3) & "," & strUser  'append it only if strUser does  not exist
                End If
                If Not userExists(strUser, CStr(arr(i, 4))) Then
                    arr(i, 4) = arr(i, 4) & "," & strUser 'append it only if strUser does  not exist
                End If
           End If
        End If
    Next i
    rngProc.Columns("D:G").Value2 = arr
End Sub

Function userExists(strUsers As String, strUser) As Boolean
    Dim arr() As String, mtch As Variant
    arr = Split(Replace(strUsers, " ", ""), ",")
    mtch = Application.match(strUser, arr, 0)
    userExists = IsNumeric(mtch)
End Function
```

The range to be processed should be placed in columns A:G.

The above code also checks if the user to be appended, or to replace an existing one **already** exists and add it only if it does not.

I made some tests using generic users, groups, as "user1", "user2" etc. and "group1", "group2" etc.

You may proceed in the same way (on a dummy workbook) or use your real user/group names and change them in the next testing sub:

```
Sub testUpdateUsers()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, rngProc As Range
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row
  Set rngProc = sh.Range("A2:G" & lastR)
  
  updateUsers rngProc, "user9", "group4", "user10"    'replace "user10" with "user9", for "group4"
  Stop 'see the replacement and press F5
  
  updateUsers rngProc, "user9", "group4", , "user1"   'append "user10" in "group4" if "user1" alredy exists
  Stop 'see the replacement and press F5
  
  updateUsers rngProc, "user13", "group4"             'append "user10" in "group4"
End Sub
```

Comment: @Adnan Tamimi I could see now your answer to my clarification questions... The above code **process both groups categories separately**. I mean it replace, append etc. for both cases individually. So, you must clearly explain how do you like the process to work.  The department is not taken in consideration in the above code. To add department between the `Sub` parameters is not very complicated (only the array columns should be changed), but I cannot understand how to act related to departments, groups and both approvers columns...